# How to autoconnect to bluetooth gamepad on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, joystick

I have an [Ipega Gamepad](http://ipega.hk/gamehandle.html). The first time I connect it to my Windows, it works. But then when I want to connect again, I turn it on and nothing happens. On the bluetooth devices list, I can see it, but there's no "connect" button, only "Remove Device".

I have to remove the device and pair again every time.

How can I make it automatically connect every time I turn the gamepad on?

I tried marking the computer as discoverable through bluetooth so the controller could see it and then connect to it but this didn't help.

Comment: Their support seems very poor to me. Do you have any other Bluetooth devices (like a mouse) and do the other devices auto connect?

Comment: @John no device autoconnect, but at least my bluetooth headphones for example do show the "connect" button on the side of the "remove device" button